# ERROR 500 NoClassDefFoundError from Jackrabbit oak AbstractLoginModule

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, aem-6, jackrabbit-oak

I have upgraded AEM 6.5 SP5 to AEM SP12 and when I spin up the server im getting this error.

```
HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/spi/security/authentication/AbstractLoginModule
URI:    /libs/granite/core/content/login.html
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/spi/security/authentication/AbstractLoginModule
SERVLET:    org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet-1d81b3db
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/spi/security/authentication/AbstractLoginModule
```

I tried to change Open JDK to Oracle JDK too but the issue was not resolved.
this is happening in Amazon Linux red hat server which i used to host the application.

Comment: Are you able to open the web console under .../system/console ?

Comment: Does it happen locally or only in the server?

Comment: i can only see this in server local works fine